# Firebase functions not working with Clerk signup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-native, expo

so I am building a React Native/Expo app. I am using Clerk as an OAuth provider and I have Firebase for things like posts... Now I have this code:

```
import { getAuth, signInWithCustomToken } from "firebase/auth";
import Toast from "react-native-toast-message";

const signInWithClerk = async (getToken: any) => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const token = await getToken({ template: "integration_firebase" });

    signInWithCustomToken(auth, token).catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        Toast.show({
            type: "error",
            text1: "Error" + errorCode,
            text2: errorMessage,
        });
    });
};

export default signInWithClerk;
```

then i have this function in my `/firebase/functions/src/index.ts`

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

export const newUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  return db
    .collection("user")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .create(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)));
});
```

but for some reason, when I call the `signInWithClerk()` in my **Home.tsx** it creates a user in the Authentication tab in Firebase admin but does not create anything in the Firestore. I use the v1 functions since it's my 1st time working with Firebase so If you know how to write this function in v2 please help, but I don't think this is the issue. Any help?

> EDIT: The function gets called but not working:
> [image]

> EDIT-2: It seems that when I manually create a user in Firebase admin it gets created in the Firestore and there is a `Mail` icon in the **Provider** column soo... anything?

EDIT-3 (final): Response from Clerk Discord Support/Admin: **"We don't offer direct integration. You'd need to fill in a tenants table with what you need from the user."**

Comment: You can check the logs for that function by going to the firebase console functions tab.

Comment: yeah well... the logs:
```
logs.protoPayload {
    request {
        requestAttributes { auth: {} }   // auth is empty for some reason
}
}
```
for me the logs doesn't provide any useful information, there is a bunch of useless data and nothing that could really help me